# How to Cache Busting in Angular Universal

Tags: angular, caching, browser-cache, angular8, angular-universal

How can i run the command of cache busting in Angular Universal?
I tried to run `npm run build:ssr --output-hashing=all`  BUT it doesn't change/add anything.

**PACKAGE.json**

```
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "compile:server": "webpack --config webpack.server.config.js --progress --colors",
    "serve:ssr": "node dist/server",
    "build:ssr": "npm run build:client-and-server-bundles && npm run compile:server",
    "build:client-and-server-bundles": "ng build --prod && ng run sample-project:server:production --bundleDependencies all"
  },
```

Comment: what is `build:ssr` in `package.json` ?

Comment: are you getting any errors?

Comment: I got no errors @Plochie

Comment: Delete `dist` if available, then after successfully running the command, check if `dist` folder is getting created or not.

Comment: @Plochie Yes the dist is creating. What i meant is, i want to put cache busting so that it would destory old cache and replace with new ones. The problem is that when i add the —output-hashing=all. It still doesnt change anything. The dist is still the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are running `npm run build:ssr --output-hashing=all`, the npm will only execute `npm run build:ssr`, and will not consider the option provided.

For this add following scripts in `package.json` and run `npm run build:ssr:outhashall`

```
...
"scripts" {
    "build:ssr:outhashall": "npm run build:client-and-server-bundles:outhashall && npm run compile:server",
    "build:client-and-server-bundles:outhashall": "ng build --prod --output-hashing=all && ng run sample-project:server:production --bundleDependencies all"
}
...
```

**Points from comments:**

Do note that `--output-hashing=all` will generate build files with hashed names, so if you have done some changes in project then you will see different file names after each build.

Hence, while deploying application, you need to remove existing files and place new files in deployment folder.

Comment: Hi! I just run your command. I git status it, and it only changes the package.json :(

Comment: It should have changes in several js files since it would have hashing?

Comment: Yes. So whats the purpose of cache busting, if you have made changes?

Comment: This is used the case you are using `ng build -prod --output-hashing none`, this will generate same name file every time. In this case you may need cache busting. I hope I am making sense.

Comment: So how can i replace the old cache when building and deploying? Would i need to run the --output-hashing=all ?

Comment: So how can i change the file names when building? My main goal really is to clear the old cache.

Comment: Please continue this discussion in https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204704/discussion-between-plochie-and-joseph

Comment: Have you tried putting Angular Universal and PWA together? Is it a good practice?

Comment: But have you tried Angular Universal and PWA separately?

Comment: Please avoid such discussion in comments. I have pasted the chat link. Also please remove comments which are not relevant to this question.