# How to effectively implement cache busting in Angular Server-Side Rendering application?

Tags: angular, server-side-rendering

I'm currently working on an Angular application and I'm having trouble implementing cache busting. The cached version of the website is still displayed to the users unless cookies are cleared.

What I need is a way to clear cache so that every time a new stance is published, it gets updated. Tried [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59450427/3952885) but configs doesn't seem to be correct. Am i missing something?

Why is this command not working? `--output-hashing=all` should clear caches, but why isn't not working. Is it because of server side rendering?

`"build:ssr": "ng build --configuration=production --output-hashing=all && ng run myapp:server"`

here is my package.json and angular.json

package.json

```
  "name": "myapp",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build --configuration production --output-hashing=all",
    "postbuild": "node licensify.js",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "bundle": "bundlewatch",
    "bundle:report": "source-map-explorer dist/myapp/*.js",
    "postinstall": "ngcc",
    "dev:ssr": "ng run myapp:serve-ssr",
    "serve:ssr": "node dist/myapp/server/main.js",
    "build:ssr": "ng build && ng run myapp:server",
    "build:ssr:outhashall": "ng run myapp:client-and-server-bundles:outhashall && npm run compile:server",
    "build:client-and-server-bundles:outhashall": "ng build --prod --output-hashing=all && ng run sample-project:server:production --bundleDependencies all",

    "prerender": "ng run myapp:prerender"
  },
```

**angular.json**

````
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "myapp": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "projectType": "application",
      "prefix": "app",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:module": {
          "skipTests": true
        }
      },
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/myapp/browser",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/ads.txt",
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets",
              "src/web.config",
              "src/manifest.json",
              "src/google43d412fda361808c.html",
              "src/sitemap.xml"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "./node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/purple-green.css",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
              "node_modules/angular-calendar/css/angular-calendar.css",
              "node_modules/cropperjs/dist/cropper.min.css",
              "node_modules/quill/dist/quill.core.css",
              "node_modules/quill/dist/quill.bubble.css",
              "node_modules/quill/dist/quill.snow.css",
              "node_modules/@ctrl/ngx-emoji-mart/picker.css",
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js",
              "node_modules/quill/dist/quill.min.js"
            ],
            "vendorChunk": true,
            "extractLicenses": false,
            "buildOptimizer": false,
            "sourceMap": false,
            "optimization": false,
            "namedChunks": true
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "6kb"
                }
                ],
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "serviceWorker": true
            },
            "development": {}
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "production"
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "myapp:build:production"
            },
            "development": {
              "browserTarget": "myapp:build:development"
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "development"
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "myapp:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "src/karma.conf.js",
            "styles": [
              "./node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/purple-green.css",
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [],
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets",
              "src/web.config",
              "src/manifest.json",
              "src/sitemap.xml"
            ]
          }
        },
        "server": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:server",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/myapp/server",
            "main": "server.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.server.json",
            "optimization": false,
            "sourceMap": true,
            "extractLicenses": false,
            "vendorChunk": true
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "outputHashing": "media",
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false
            },
            "development": {}
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "production"
        },
        "serve-ssr": {
          "builder": "@nguniversal/builders:ssr-dev-server",
          "configurations": {
            "development": {
              "browserTarget": "myapp:build:development",
              "serverTarget": "myapp:server:development"
            },
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "myapp:build:production",
              "serverTarget": "myapp:server:production"
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "development"
        },
        "prerender": {
          "builder": "@nguniversal/builders:prerender",
          "options": {
            "routes": [
              "/"
            ]
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "myapp:build:production",
              "serverTarget": "myapp:server:production"
            },
            "development": {
              "browserTarget": "myapp:build:development",
              "serverTarget": "myapp:server:development"
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "production"
        }
      }
    },
    "myapp-e2e": {
      "root": "e2e/",
      "projectType": "application",
      "architect": {
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "devServerTarget": "myapp:serve:production"
            },
            "development": {
              "devServerTarget": "myapp:serve:development"
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "development"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "cli": {
    "analytics": false
  }
}```
````

Comment: Maybe this is a problem? https://angular.io/guide/deployment#server-configuration (outcome: Never cache `index.html`)

Comment: A possibility might be that you have a serviceworker caching everything?? _(because maybe you have a bad pwa setup)_

Comment: Can you check to make sure you're not caching `index.html`? Open up the `index.html` in Chrome, and verify that the URL of the JS file in Chrome is the same as the new JS file you just created from `ng build`. (If not, you may not be properly replacing the index.html because you didn't copy it to the correct place, or it's possible that one of your caching tools (Your `cdn`, or your `loadbalancer`, or someone) is caching the `index.html`, so it's not pointing towards the new JS file.

Comment: index.html was being cached, i changed few settings. And now i guess the issue is resolved. Because its not longer cached. @EliezerBerlin

Comment: @AmirDora That makes sense. I wrote it out as a proper answer.

Answer (score 0):

Angular implements cache-busting by changing the name of the JS file (with a random name) every time you run ng build.

If your cache-busting isn't working, likely the **index.html** itself is being cached, because the JS itself wouldn't be possible to cache (As the HTML no longer links to the old JS file.)

There's a few places the `index.html` might be cached:

1. Server-side (Via `OPCache` or `Litespeed` or something, though this unlikely, since generally plugins like OPCache shouldn't cache `HTML`, only `PHP`.)
2. In your `loadbalancer` or `proxy server`.
3. In your `CDN`.

(For example, often `CDN`s like to implement caching of HTML, in order to implement `Always On` availability[So the website doesn't go down even if your server does] or simply to serve the HTML directly from a local datacenter instead of forwarding every request halfway across the globe to your real server.)

---

A simple way to verify that the HTML isn't being cached is to just open up the `index.html` in Chrome, and verify that the `URL of the JS file in Chrome` is the same as `the name of the new JS file you just created from ng build`. If it's the same, then your HTML isn't being cached, and the cache-busting is working correctly.

---

If it IS being cached, then you have a few choices:

1. Disable HTML caching.
2. Log into your `CDN/Loadbalancer/Whatever` and press the "Clear Cache" button every time you update the code.
3. Many services support using `API Keys` for automatically clearing cache from within a script, though this is generally complicated to set up unless you have a plugin that does it for you. (For example, Cloudflare's cache can be via e.g. [npm script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38122334/clearing-cloudflare-cache-programmatically) or [a bookmark](https://community.cloudflare.com/t/worker-recipe-cache-purge-proxy/29978).)
4. Or, if you want, simply accept the fact that most people will continue to see the old version of your code for a couple days and don't implement cache-busting at all.

Comment: js files were being hashed already, it was index.html in this case. Accepted, thanks :)